# Where is my coworker from?

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, steganography, computer-puzzle

My new coworker sent me some code. He wants me to figure out where he was born. I believe there are some hints within the code, but I cannot figure it out. Here is the code block:

```
function sort(arr){

    var len = arr.length;      
    for (var i = len-1; i>=0; i--){
        for(var j = 1; j<=i; j++){
            if(arr[j-1]>arr[j]){
                var temp = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Evidently, the code doesn't run. Can you help me figure out where he's from?

Comment: Holy mother of; oh wait, haha! Great puzzle yet again casey! I feel like I should be looking at syntactical errors. Is this `JavaScript`?

Comment: Looks like rot 13(ohooyr fbeg) with some modification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your character was born in

> Greece!

The code looked perfectly fine,

> so I copied and pasted it into JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/.

Strangely,

> JSFiddle seemed to tell me that the semicolons at the end of each line were invalid, even though they look completely valid to me.

I was confused by this, but after I thought for a bit, I suspected that

> the semicolons were not actually semicolons at all, but the Unicode "Greek question mark" character.

I confirmed this by

> looking at the Unicode code points in your post. The one at the end of each line is U+037E GREEK QUESTION MARK instead of U+003B SEMICOLON.

Comment: Correct! Well done. :)